# Session hijacking using desktop application

Tags: cookies, browser, session-hijacking

Is it possible to create a windows application that can read the session cookies of a specific browser tab or of a specific domain, and use that for for example session hijacking by sending the cookie to a malicious user who enters it in his browser?

As I read it, cookies are stored in local files. And if so then it is possible? Or have I missed something here?

Thanks
Jihad

Comment: Too broad: not all browsers work in the same way. E.g. whether session cookies are stored on disk is an implementation detail.

Comment: OK Fine. But if we take one of the major browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox) are there any of them where this is possible?